# Android add external JAR with a variable

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project, where external JARs were configured using an eclipse external variable, that used to work fine for build/run in devices and emulators.

I have updated to the latest Android eclipse plug-in and SDK tools and this doesn't longer works, if i copy my jar file to libs sub directory and add it to build path it works (builds/runs).

When i use the variable with external JAR it builds fine, but classes are missing when try to run.

I want to use the external JAR with a variable and avoid to copy the file to libs//

is that still possible, any ideas why this isn't working in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries now need to be marked as exported, i found the info here http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects